# Can anybody rephrase this sentence for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Increased regulatory burden translates to more hours [worked] with no positive impact on output."

source: http://money.cnn.com/2016/08/23/news/economy/us-economy-low-productivity/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rephrase this sentence in several ways. One of the simplest versions of this sentence could be:

> Increased regulatory burden leads to more working hours without any positive impact on output.

However, it is difficult to give a precise answer without knowing the context. One can help you after getting your requirement.

Btw, as per [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/translate) 'translate into something' means to convert something. Say, an increased regulatory burden converts into more working hours.